# null is not assignable to void when flag --strictNullChecks is enabled

Tags: typescript

As per the TypeScript Documentation:

> However, when using the **--strictNullChecks** flag, *null* and *undefined* are only assignable to *void* and *their respective types*. This helps avoid many common errors. In cases where you want to pass in either a string or null or undefined, you can use the union type *string | null | undefined*. Once again, more on union types later on.

But, when I tried following code snippets:

```
// This worked correctly
let voidIsUndefined: void = undefined;

// While following code thrown a compilation error "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void'."
let voidIsNull: void = null;
```

It did not work completely as expected.

As per the docs, I should be able to assign *null* to void type. Can someone please clear this doubt?

Comment: That is by design. Void is a concept that only exists in the type space. A function that lacks a return statement would be considered void from the perspective of the type system yet actually returns the undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) are misleading and you're correct to feel confused. There is an issue about this here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/468

Comment: Thanks @Shaun Luttin, for the clarification.